# Dynalic listview builder flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, dynamic, refresh

I am trying to develop a function where the listview is refreshed/rerun whenever a button is clicked.I have tried it with setState but haven't got the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListView under RefreshIndicator.

On your RefreshIndicator, add a function called onRefresh():

void onRefresh(){
...
}

RefreshIndicator(
onRefresh: onRefresh,
child: ListView.separated(
...
),
),

You can then call the function by adding it on your button.